# Using PHP and MySQL how do I populate one table using some field values from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a database project on which one of the forms table need to be filled with some values from another table using a select box.

Table one is called `reg_table` and has the following fields:

```
RegNo | Surname | Othernames | Assembly
-------------------------------------------------
00001 | John    | Okon       | Glory Assembly
00002 | Peter   | Dan        | Shepherds Assembly
00003 | Ada     | Victor     | Pnuema Assembly
```

and table two is called `valparts_table` and has the following together will all the fields of table one as seen below

```
CountID  | MTNumber | Camping | Hostel    |  RegNo | Surname | Othernames | Assembly
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
00001    | 0002     | Yes     | Hostel-1  |  00001 | John    | Okon       | Glory Assembly
00002    | 0003     | No      | Hostel-2  |  00002 | Peter   | Dan        | Shepherds Assembly
00003    | 0004     | Yes     | Hostel-3  |  00003 | Ada     | Victor     | Pnuema Assembly
```

1. Now when you open the valpartsfrm form and select a Surname value using a select box object on the valpartsfrm form that is linked to reg_table, it will show all the Surnames. When you select a Surname from the list, it should fill the following filds on the valpartsfrm with the values of RegNo Surname Othernames Assembly from the reg_table.
2. Once this is done, you then manually fill the remaining valpartsfrm form fields (MTNumber,  Camping Hostel)

Please note that the `valparts_table` is bound to the valpartsfrm form.

The link http://dbms.rmww.org/images/validatepart.jpg shows a sample of the database developed using MS Access 2007

Comment: Could you specify the database engine of the two tables?

Comment: you are repeating some columns in your database. You do not need to repeat those column

Comment: @Ruben Giaquinto: I am sorry I missed out that. I am using MySQL with PHP

Comment: @ Awlad Liton: The repeated columns are in another table and will be filled automatically when a Surname that matches the row is selected. For example if you select Peter from te select box, it will fill the other text boxes with 00002    |    Peter   |   Dan         |  Shepherds Assembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i thing you want to fill your form as you select the option 
try this code

its form demo

in this select box has option value which in json string and a onchange function

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Select Surname</td>
    <td>
        <select id="my_select" onchange="javascript:fill_form(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `reg_table` ") or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
            {
              $key = json_encode($row);
              echo "<option value='".$key."'>".$row['Surname']."</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>RegNo</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="RegNo" id="RegNo" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Surname</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="Surname" id="Surname" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Othernames</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="Othernames" id="Othernames" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Assembly</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="" name="Assembly" id="Assembly" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

this js function call when you change the select box option 
in this json string is deoceded in object and fill the textboxes accordingly

```
<script>
function fill_form(json_string)
{   

   if(json_string=="")
   {
        document.getElementById('RegNo').value = "";
        document.getElementById('Surname').value = "";
        document.getElementById('Othernames').value = "";
        document.getElementById('Assembly').value = "";
   }
   else
   {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(json_string); // json string to object 
        document.getElementById('RegNo').value = jsonData.RegNo;
        document.getElementById('Surname').value = jsonData.Surname;
        document.getElementById('Othernames').value = jsonData.Othernames;
        document.getElementById('Assembly').value = jsonData.Assembly;
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I will implement it and see. Should I just copy the codes and paste behind the valpartsfrm form without any modification?

Comment: Ok I will. I am using Dreamweaver as my development software